# Open source folder to folder sync for Windows

Tags: windows, sync, open-source

I was wondering if there is open source project for windows based system were I could sync two folder within the same operating system.

I have done some jobs for clients with comercial versions of [PeerSync](http://www.peersoftware.com/products/peersync/peersync.aspx) and [Double-Take](http://www.visionsolutions.com/Products/DT-Avail.aspx) but I find that some work that I do does not require lot of features thous two offer and I could manage with open source project in most cases, but I was not able to find one.

I'm not interested in build-in windows features that would do the job - just to avoid TIPS on how to do it.

The sync should be process always running and waiting for file system triggers. Sync should not have to be triggered manually.

Comment: Do you really need "Open Source" or are you just looking for "Free"?

Comment: Open source since I would like to learn about the System API and triggers.

Comment: FindFirstChangeNotification http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28VS.85%29.aspx (native) and FileSystemWatcher http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx (.NET) is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-folder-synchronization-utility.htm) lists:

- [Pure Synch](http://www.jumpingbytes.com/en/puresync.html)
- [FreeFileSynch](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/)
- [Allway Synch](http://www.allwaysync.com/)

But only FreeFileSynch appears to be open source and non-commercial.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [**PureSync**](http://www.jumpingbytes.com/en/puresync.html). The free version has everything you're looking for and then some. Excellent software.

It features user-definable synchronization triggers, including an automatic sync upon file/folder modification.
[image]